# Are TemplateObject arrays for tagged template literals weakly referenced by their realm?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-strings, weakmap, tagged-templates

```
while (c) {
  tag`str0 ${e} str1`
}
```

The JavaScript runtime creates a frozen array like `Object.freeze(['str0 ', ' str1'])` but with an additional `.raw` property.

Is it okay to use that object as a key in a `WeakMap` to avoid having to redo work based on the array each time through the loop?

```
const memoTable = new WeakMap
function tag(templateStrings, ...values) {
  let cached = memoTable.get(templateStrings)
  if (!cached) {
    // Compute cached and put it in the table for next time.
  }
  // Do something with cached and values
}
```

Section [12.2.9.3 Runtime Semantics: GetTemplateObject ( *templateLiteral* )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-gettemplateobject) describes how this value is cached:

> 2. Let *realm* be the current Realm Record.
> 3. Let *templateRegistry* be *realm*.[[TemplateMap]].

so it should be the same from use to use of `tag` in the loop above which would be a nice property for a key to have.

It seems to me that the [[TemplateMap]] would have to weakly reference the template object array because otherwise

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; ++i) {
  eval('(() => {})`' + i + '`');
}
```

would leak memory.

I don't see anything in the specification but is it the case for widely used JavaScript engines that WeakMap entries for tagged string template uses not in re-enterable scopes will eventually be collected?

I ask because I've implemented [something](https://www.npmjs.com/package/template-tag-common) based on this assumption but haven't figured out how to test it.

Comment: But how would you actually get something from the Map? Same templateStrings does not mean that the array it is stored in has the same reference. Or am i missing something?

Comment: @JonasW. My understanding of step 4 from the spec (If e.[[Strings]] and rawStrings contain the same values in the same order, then Return e.[[Array]].) combined with step 14 means that it is the same array.

Comment: Interesting. Seems like you are right. However, it doesnt feel very javascriptish

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it okay to use that object as a key in a WeakMap to avoid having to redo work based on the array each time through the loop?

Yep, that's exactly what you're meant to do and it's one of the great features of template literals.

> It seems to me that the [[TemplateMap]] would have to weakly reference the template object array because otherwise
>
> ```
> for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; ++i) {
>   eval('(() => {})`' + i + '`');
> }
> ```
>
> would leak memory.

It does leak in fact, since `[[TemplateMap]]` is not weak. :(

This is an open point of discussion on the current spec. The discussion as of this writing is whether the spec should be changed to have template literals be be per-source-text-position instead of having the `[[TemplateMap]]` be global state. e.g. as of this writing:

```
var id = v => v;
id`tpl` === id`tpl` // true
```

which is a bit weird.

Is it acceptable to break that such that two separate templates are created? If so, then there's at least the possibility that your `eval` example could be allowed to collect the template.

You can see some discussion here, https://github.com/tc39/ecma262/issues/840, where at least tentatively this could be fixed.

### EDIT:

The spec did indeed change, so templates are now per-source-location instead of per-realm, so two templates with the same content and different locations will be two different objects. This means that engines can potentially garbage-collect template literal object if their source file is no longer reachable.

Comment: +1 for digging up                                                                                        
                     that issue!

Comment: Ah, I see.   IIRC, when I drafted the strawman that I wrote it in terms of a declaration hoisted to the top of the compilation unit, but a per call-site array would complicate inlining and loop unrolling by tools like ClosureCompiler.

Comment: It would complicate that, true, but you could always wrap it in a function and leave it to the JIT to inline the function. I'm definitely not a fan of the hoisting because of the leak concerns.

Comment: @loganfsmyth could you explain purpose of `[[TemplateMap]]`? By the way "id`tpl` === id`tpl`" is not true

Comment: @MaximPro It is not true now, but it _was_ true at the time of the question, hence the "right now" I had in there.

Comment: @loganfsmyth well, do you know anything about `[[TemplateMap]]` field? Specs doesn't explain it purpose and sense.

Comment: @loganfsmyth also I've asked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71894475/what-is-the-templatemap-field-for-in-realm). If it is not hard for you, you could give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to me that the [[TemplateMap]] would have to weakly reference the template object array

I don't know what implementations actually do here, but the spec does indeed describe the realms [[TemplateMap]] as never being emptied. Evaling many different template tags in a loop would indeed heavily leak memory, so [don't do that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DxOsn09iPA).

> Is it okay to use that object as a key in a WeakMap to avoid having to redo work?

Yes, that's perfectly fine. If the global [[TemplateMap]] does leak memory, this will intensify the problem, but when it doesn't then by using a *weak* map you are not causing a problem.

Comment: Good point.  I can exacerbate a problem within a long-lived realm, but not create a problem that isn't there.