# ECMAScript 2017, I can't understand Realm.[[TemplateMap]]

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017, ecma262

I'm writing some article that about ECMA-262's realm in korean(actually there is no article about realm). So, I read ECMA-262 about realm record.and i can understand about [[Intrinsics]], [[GlobalObject]] and etc.. But, I can't understand about [[TemplateMap]].

1.How template literal save in [[TemplateMap]].(need some example about [[TemplateMap]]'s content)

Comment: [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48528281/1048572) might give you some food for thought.

Comment: I think your first question "I don't understand feature XY" is too broad for SO - what in particular do you not understand? How it works (at which step)? What its purpose is? Why it was designed that way? We might be able to help you with the second part though.

Comment: Thank you for answer.I raed that case, but i still can't figure out. I just want to know how template literal save in [[TemplateMap]]. So - if you can show me some example about [[TemplateMap]]'s content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entries of the [[TemplateMap]] are of the format "*Record {[[Strings]]: `rawStrings`, [[Array]]: `template`}*". `template` is the frozen template object that is passed to the tag function, and `rawStrings` are a list of [raw template values](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-static-semantics-tv-and-trv) of the literal - basically the same as the `.raw` array.